# how to read vitals info, like body temperature, blood pressure in my python web-app

Tags: google-fit

I am able to read heartrate, but facing problem reading body temp, and blood pressure,

```
api_url =       'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm/datasets/1692588599000000000-1692642599000000000'

headers = {
       'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
response = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
print("response: ",response.text)
```

tried using
api_url =     'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.body.temperature:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input/datasets/1692588599000000000-1692642599000000000'

```
headers = {
       'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
response = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
print("response: ",response.text)
```